# Can publishProgress be overloaded in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to publish two different kinds of progress in my background process. I am trying to publish a string sometime and an integer another time. I am handling both kinds of arguments in the onProgressUpdate by overloading them too. But when I declare my AsyncTask class, I have the arguments  that is why it is expecting me to send only string type arguments. Is there a way to handle both type of publishProgress events?

Comment: There is no way using the standard AsyncTask to do this - you either have to use a type that both types can conform to, or implement your own AsyncTask.

Comment: Ii am implementing the SensorEventListener class in my activity in which I have nested my AsyncTask class. Can't I just make a string global variable and update the variable in the AsyncTask and the onSensorChanged() method will pick up the variable and set it to the text? Can i totally avoid postProgress() method?

Comment: That would be a very bad design strategy if I understand you correcly. It would be much better to create your own implementation of AsyncTask that will support multiple update methods, such that you are not limited to only 1 method. Alternatively you can just always use strings in your publishUpdate() method, and then in your onProgressUpdate() you can check whether the string is an integer (using Integer.parseInt(your string)) or not and act accordingly.

Comment: If it will help you I can give you an example of implementing your own AsyncTask with multiple update methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are two ways to address your issue:

The first one is very simple, where you just always `publishUpdate(String)`, and then in your `onProgressUpdate(String)` checks whether the string is an int or a string, and handle each case differently like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    //Executed on main UI thread.
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
        try{
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            TextView v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            v1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            TextView v2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            v2.setText(values[0]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 100){
            try {
                if(i%2 == 0){
                    publishProgress("Divisible by 2: " + String.valueOf(i));
                }
                publishProgress(String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the above example I just try and parse the string to an `Integer` - if it works then I am 100% sure it is an int - if it throws an exception then it is a `String`.

If you want more control however, you need to implement your own version of AsyncTask, that support one or more progress updates. The only way you can achieve this is by using `Handlers` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and `Thread` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) directly (preferably wrapped in a more logical class similar to AsyncTask):

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

public abstract class DIYAsyncTask<Params, IntProgress, StringProgress, Result> {

    private Result backGroundResult;

    //Run on UI thread
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void execute(Params... params){
        final Params[] thisParams = params;
        Thread worker = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                prepareForPreExecute();
                backGroundResult = doInBackground(thisParams);
                prepareForPostExecute();
            }
        };
        worker.setPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        worker.start();
    }

    //Code to start onPreExecute on UI thread
    private void prepareForPreExecute(){
        Handler ui_handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        ui_handler.post(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        onPreExecute();
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    //Code to start onPostExecute on UI thread
    private void prepareForPostExecute(){
        Handler ui_handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        ui_handler.post(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        onPostExecute(backGroundResult);
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    //Always run on worker thread
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);

    //Always run on UI
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    //Always run on UI
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result){
    }

    //Run on worker
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishIntProgress(IntProgress... values){
        Handler ui_handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final IntProgress[] thisProgress = values;
        ui_handler.post(
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        onIntProgressUpdate(thisProgress);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //Always run on UI
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void onIntProgressUpdate(IntProgress... values){

    }

    //Run on worker
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishStringProgress(StringProgress... values){
        Handler ui_handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final StringProgress[] thisProgress = values;
        ui_handler.post(
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        onStringProgressUpdate(thisProgress);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //Always run on UI
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void onStringProgressUpdate(StringProgress... values){

    }
}
```

Which you can then override like this (notice the similarity to just using AsyncTask)

```
private class MyDIYAsyncTask extends DIYAsyncTask<Void, Integer, String, Void> {

    //Executed on main UI thread.
    @Override
    protected void onIntProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onIntProgressUpdate(values); 
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        v.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStringProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onStringProgressUpdate(values);
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        v.setText(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 100){
            try {
                publishIntProgress(i);
                publishStringProgress("MyString" + String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```